# Comparing a string from the web

Tags: iphone, ios4

hey all, i'm trying to read a file on the web that says "this is a test" and i wanna compare it... so here's what i got:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/test.asp"];
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:theURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",test); //prints the results.. .does work


if(test == "this is a test"){
    NSLog(@"File read");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Bad file");
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? I always get "Bad file" but i know it's pulling in the text. Thanks all

damien

Answer (score 4):

You need to check for nil as well & use isEqualToString function for comparison.

```
if(test != nil){

    if([test isEqualToString:@"this is a test"]) {
       // equal
    }
    else{
      // not equal
    }
}

else{

   NSLog(@"Bad file");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... check out what i wrote below... unfortunately, i didn't get an email for this comment. I didn't even know it was here until after reading the one below. Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `==`, you'll be comparing two pointers. Use `isEqual:` like so:

```
if([test isEqual: @"this is a test"]) {
    // equal
}else{
    // not equal
}
```

Comment: ohhhhh...... and what if i wanted to compare an int from the web.... would it be something like this.. 

if([(int) test isEqual:1]){
   etc...
}

? Also, how would i convert this into a switch statement? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Other than the 2 answer you can also use.

```
– caseInsensitiveCompare:
– localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:
– compare:
– localizedCompare:
– compare:options:
– compare:options:range:
– compare:options:range:locale:
– localizedStandardCompare:
```